# Confusion in Word Size in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I have the following code, in x86 assembly, which tries to print X on the screen:

```
mov ah , 0x0e
mov al , the_secret
int 0x10 
mov al , [the_secret]
int 0x10 
mov bx , the_secret
add bx , 0x7c00
mov al , [bx]
int 0x10 
mov al , [0x7c1e]
int 0x10 
jmp $ ; Jump forever.
the_secret :
db " X "
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

When I check the above code in GDB I found that jmp $ command is stored in address 0x7c1b. But GDB shows different data sizes at different addresses. For example:

```
(gdb) p/x *0x7c1e
$5 = 0x2058
(gdb) p/x *0x7c1b
$6 = 0x5820feeb
(gdb) p/x *0x7c1d
$7 = 0x205820
```

Sometimes it gives 2 bytes sometimes 4 bytes or 3bytes. Shouldn't it print 2bytes always, which is the word size in x86 (since I am in real mode). Why is it showing different sizes of data at these addresses?
I am also showing the hex dump created after assembling the above assembly code:

```
7c00: b4 0e b0 1d cd 10 a0 1d 00 cd 10 bb 1d 00 81 c3
7c10: 00 7c 8a 07 cd 10 a0 1e 7c cd 10 eb fe 20 58 20
7c20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually getting four bytes every time, it's just that, if the upper bytes are zero, it doesn't show them in the output, for the same reason that you wouldn't write seven as `00000007`.

For example, in printing out the two-byte value of 64<sub>10</sub>, you would see `0x40`. If the two-byte vale was 12345<sub>10</sub>, you'd see `0x3039`.

From your hex dump, you can see this sequence:

```
7c1b: eb fe 20 58 20 00 00
```

So, at the given addresses, you see the bytes (and value with high zero bytes not printed):

```
7c1b: eb fe 20 58 (5820feeb)
7c1d: 20 58 20 00 (  205820)
7c1e: 58 20 00 00 (    2058)
```

Comment: thanks....but since we are in the real mode, shouldn't the word size be 16 bits for x86??

Comment: @sarthak, obviously _not_ :-) I'm not sure real mode dictates the size of an integer in `gcc`, and the `p/x` command simply will "regard the bits of the value as an integer, and print the integer in hexadecimal". If `gdb` had a type to work with, maybe it could figure it out, but `*0x7c1e` does not have a type like `*myvar` would. That's my guess anyway.